# Is there a way to script a ghci session?

Tags: bash, haskell, ghci

My goal is to pipe some steps for `ghci` to run from a bash script and then exit cleanly. The commentary online [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8676361/15441) to use `runhaskell` for this.

This is the [command](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness) I'm trying to run:

```
ghci> import System.Random 

ghci> random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Int, StdGen)
```

With expected result similar to:

```
(-3633736515773289454,693699796 2103410263)
```

When I drop this into a file `randomtest.hs` and execute it with `runhaskell` I get the following error:.

```
randomtest.hs:3:1: error:
    Invalid type signature: random (mkStdGen 100) :: ...
    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

It seems I can't use the `runhaskell` method to blindly execute `ghci` inputs.

Now the way to work around this is to add extra commands to the file that is passed to `runhaskell`:

```
main = do print (random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Int, StdGen))
```

My goal is to automate the running of ghci work for a haskell course I'm using. I want to be able to run the ghci command from a bash script - in the format that ghci expects, and have it cleanly exit from ghci (or whatever runs it).

My question is: **Is there a way to script a ghci session?**

Comment: Have you tried just piping the script into GHCi via the shell? E.g.: `ghci < filename`. If you just want to run some commands and then exit, that should work fine.

Comment: Thanks @JonPurdy - I tried that - and got the output, but in a long sequence of commands, without seeing the input it was difficult to see where you were up to - and sometimes excluded newlines. This would work in a pinch, but I'm open to something better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) for that, it allows you to interactively control a REPL with simple commands. This script does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

log_user 0
spawn ghci
log_user 1

expect ".*> "
send ":set prompt \"ghci> \"\n"

expect "ghci> "
send "import System.Random\n"
expect "ghci> "
send "random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Int, StdGen)\n"

interact
```

Running this gives you the following:

```
$ ./ghci-interactive
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set prompt "ghci> "
ghci> import System.Random
ghci> random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Int, StdGen)
(-3633736515773289454,693699796 2103410263)
ghci>
```

Note: You might need to adjust this a bit to be resistant to users setting the prompt in `~/.ghci`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @SilvanMosberger - you solved the issue so I'll leave yours as correct.

I wanted to generalise this approach so it could load instructions specified in a file - eg `RandomPair.ghci` with the following contents:

```
import System.Random 

random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Int, StdGen)  
random (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Float, StdGen)  
random (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Bool, StdGen)  
random (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Integer, StdGen)
```

Now a script to run this looks like the file `RandomPair-ghci.bash`

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

log_user 0
spawn ghci
log_user 1

expect ".*> "
send ":set prompt \"ghci> \"\n"

set f [open "RandomPair.ghci"]
set replcommands [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach replcommand $replcommands {
    set replcommand1 [string map {"\"" "\\\""} $replcommand] 

    expect "ghci> "
    send -- "$replcommand1 \n"
}

expect "ghci> "
send ":quit\n"

interact
```

This gives a result similar to:

```
$ ./RandomPair-ghci.bash 
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set prompt "ghci> "
ghci> import System.Random  
ghci>  
ghci>  
ghci> random (mkStdGen 100) :: (Int, StdGen)   
(-3633736515773289454,693699796 2103410263)
ghci> random (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Float, StdGen)   
(0.3718226,1597344447 1655838864)
ghci> random (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Bool, StdGen)   
(False,1485632275 40692)
ghci> random (mkStdGen 949488) :: (Integer, StdGen)  
(9159618695640234475,587416689 2103410263)
ghci>  
ghci>  
ghci> :quit
Leaving GHCi.
$
```